# I don't get how this program is working

Tags: java

```
public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a;
        String b = "*";
        int d = 0;

        for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            for (int c = 10; c > d; c--) {
                System.out.print(b);
            }
            System.out.println();
            d = d - 2;
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints out an incrementing star pattern.

```
**********
************
**************
****************
******************
********************
**********************
************************
**************************
****************************
```

It works fine but I thought this would print a decrementing star pattern. Can anyone please explain how this program is working? I'm relatively new to Java.

Comment: Look closely at the inner loop.

Comment: Print values of `d` after you change it. You probably wanted `d = d + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a few interesting things here.

At the first interation of your outer for-loop, the inner loop starts off with values: c = 10, d = 0, next iteration: c = 10, d = -2, next.. c = 10, d = -4 and etc. So first it will print 10 stars, then 12 stars, then 14 stars...

Hope this helps.

change

```
for (int c = 10; c > d; c--)
```

to

```
for (int c = 10; c > a; c--)
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The outer for loop

```
(a = 0; a < 10; a++) {...}
```

basically represents the number of rows it will print starting from 0 to 9. For every row or a, d gets decremented by 2. 
So for

```
a = 0, c goes from 10 to 1 (d = 0) printing 10 '*'s
a = 1, c goes from 10 to -1 (d = -2) printing 12 '*'s
a = 2, c goes from 10 to -3 (d = -4) printing 14 '*'s and so on
```

With every row, d goes down by 2 causing the number of stars to go up by 2.